# How do half link chains perform for long term use?

Tags: chain, performance, single-speed

I was wondering if there is anyone with a Rohloff hub riding using a half link chain for its longevity. OK, the hub isn't essential it's just a single speed chain, so experience from anyone who rides more than the guy in the review on that page below is welcome.

http://www.chainreactioncycles.com/Models.aspx?ModelID=31089

These chains are said to be very rigid. Good. But do they last as long as other high-end single speed chains?

best
Hecke

Answer (score 3):

The only experience I have had with half link chains was on my single speed mountain bike conversion. On the upside the chain looked really good on the downside the bike started to creak like you wouldn't believe. After dismantling and greasing hubs, bottom brackets, seat posts, chain ring bolts, saddle bolts... I finally tracked it down to the half link chain, new chain and the bike was once more silent.

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, I used to ride a half-link on a BMX bike, and it did not make much of a difference even when I was beating on it.  I also put in many miles on it (it was my only ride at the time) and never had a problem or noticed a difference.  The only advantage was that it allow me to run pretty much any gearing I wanted with smaller dropouts.  I eventually replaced it with a KMC Kool Chain and noticed no difference.

Now I ride a Black Market Mob with some generic KMC single-speed chain, and I also beat on this chain.  I also commuted 10 miles round trip with hills on this bike for a long time.  Never had any problems.  Maybe I'm just lucky.

I did have the problem that Jackon had with the creaking, but giving it a spritz of Superlube once in while did the trick every time.  I've never heard of anyone comparing half-links to normal chains on a bike with an internally gearing hub.  If you're willing to drop the coin, I say find out what happens.